# Combustion of cyanamide in a bomb calorimeter at constant volume and at 25°C

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> In a bomb calorimeter, cyanamide was subjected to combustion at constant volume, and the heat evolved was found to be $\pu{742.7 KJ}$ at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$. Find $q_p$.

This is a question in my textbook. Given in the question that the volume is constant so how are we going to find $q_p$? Since it's a bomb calorimeter so pressure isn't constant. Is the question wrong?

Comment: In the given question we are asked to find qp

Comment: Okay, what is qp?

Comment: qp is the heat transfer at constant pressure

Comment: Well ! qp is probably the heat $\ce{Q_p}$ produced at constant pressure. The given data is probably $\ce{Q_v = \Delta U}$. And the unit is probably $kJ/mol$ and not $kJ$. So, in my interpretation, the author wants to get $\Delta H$. To pass from $\Delta U$ to $\Delta H$, it is necessary to know the change in gaseous moles in the combustion reaction. And the equation is probably : $\ce{CN2H2 + 1.5 O2 -->  CO2  +  H2O + N2}$ Now please do the calculation of $\Delta n$, then $\Delta n ·RT$, and you get $\Delta H$.